# why is it raising a File I/O Closed Exception while using "a+" param?

Tags: python, file, exception, io

I am encountering that it is raising an exception because it seems to be closed, to clarify more, this is the exception: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

I am trying to read a file with the objective of check if a line is contained in it, in case that it is not included, it is written in it, at the last line, so for that reason I am using `a+` param in `open` function.

Technical details to understand the context: `self.learn` is an attribute of this features:

`open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), r"Api\learn.txt"), "a+", encoding="utf-8")`

Conflicting Code:

```
 with self.learn as contentRead:
              for lines in contentRead:
               if not stripD in lines:
                 contentRead.write(stripD)
```

Example of use:

> 1. Abstract:

Creation of `class` Test where explicitly implements the function and attribute before post.

> 2. Example test:

Imagine that I execute the script two times, the expected functionality is that the first time, as the word "testWord" is not included in text file, is written, meanwhile that the second time is not written because it was written before.

> 3. Example Class

```
class test:
 def __init__(self):
  self.learn = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), r"Api\learn.txt"), "a+", encoding="utf-8")

 def testMethod(self, param):
     with self.learn as contentRead:
              for lines in contentRead:
               if not param in lines:
                 contentRead.write(param)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  instanceInvoker = test()
  try:
     instanceInvoker.testMethod("testWord")
  except Exception as exc:
     print(exc)
```

Comment: Please, post [mre]

Comment: also, it's `a+`, not `+a`

Comment: done, check it out again @buran

Comment: `with` closes the file at the end of the block. So you can’t execute it twice.

Comment: That code will not produce the error you show. The first problem is that "a+" opens at the end of the file. There are no more lines it iterate so `for lines in contentRead:` doesn't do anything. You could add a print to see. Its hard to read and write the same file because you need to continually update the file pointer (e.g., seek and tell). But those methods are not reliable in text mode files that may read ahead.

Comment: Opening the file in `__init__` but closing it in `testMethod` sort of defeats the purpose of using the `with` statement at all. The file never gets closed unless you actually call `testMethod`. If you don't want to use the file immediately after opening it, make `test` itself a context manager. (Open the file in `__enter__`, close it in `__exit__`.)